# Reload Facebook Like widget after changing data-href attribute programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am creating a web application where a user can insert Facebook Like button in the page. He clicks "Insert Facebook Like" and the widget code is being inserted, looking like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>' +
        '<script>(function(d, s, id) {' +
        'var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];' +
        'if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}' +
        'js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;' +
        'js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";' +
        'fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);' +
        '}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>' +
        '<div class="fb-like" data-href="' + field.url + '" data-send="true" data-width="369" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Then the user clicks "Edit the widget" button and sees a text input with URL. He fills in any URL he wants and clicks "Save". After this `data-href` gets the URL value.
Everything above works fine but the widget doesn't reload when the url is updated. I suppose I should call some method to reload the widget. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I was aware, the `data-href` attribute is read once when the script above it is executed. and the `div` itself becomes a container, and doesn't actually play any part in the Like process after the script's execution.

You can try using a XFBML Like-buttons instead.

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

When the user change's the URL, you would just destroy the existing Like-button, insert the updated XFBML, then using [Facebook's JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), call [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) to re-create it.